# Disable Keyguard upon receiving SMS

Tags: android

I am developing an SMS android application. One of the feature, I want to add is upon receiving an SMS the screen lock will be automatically disabled so that user need not unlock to read the message.

Is this possible? I tried few examples but those are the working. E.g [How to Disable Keyguard and display an activity to the user when receiver of SCREEN_ON is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234156/how-to-disable-keyguard-and-display-an-activity-to-the-user-when-receiver-of-scr)

Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: if the screen auto unlocks upon receiving a message, wouldn't there be a possibility of messages being sent if the message come through while the phone is in the users pocket?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this :

```
KeyguardManager  myKGuard = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
myLock = myKGuard.newKeyguardLock("com.example.myapp.Main");
myLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Also please note you will need to add DISABLE_KEYGUARD Permission to the manifest as well.

Hope this helps!

This is deprecated as of API 13 as well.

> Use FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and/or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED instead; this allows you to seamlessly hide the keyguard as your application moves in and out of the foreground and does not require that any special permissions be requested. Handle returned by newKeyguardLock(String) that allows you to disable / reenable the keyguard.

That is what Google says as of now !