# Keyguard is shown briefly before Activity is launched when using FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I'm using the following flags in `onAttachedToWindow()` to show my `Activity` above the keyguard:

`FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`

This works fine, however, when launching my activity from a background service while the screen was off, *the keyguard sometimes shows for 1-2 seconds* before my app is displayed. This happens particularly on slower phones (or in low memory situations). I find this strange, since my understanding was that `onAttachedToWindow()` is called *after* `onCreate()`/`onResume()`, so all the "heavy work" should already have been completed when the flags mentioned above are being set? Is there any way to only show my `Activity` once it has been completely set up?

Comment: I am also encountering this same issue. Would love an answer.

Comment: Are you doing anything particularly heavy in `onResume()`?

Comment: I've put together a sample app using the same flags you're specifying and even on a PoS LG Ally, I can't reproduce the keyguard delay you're describing.

Can you post some sample code from your launcher activity and the manifest? Thanks!

Comment: @A--C, yes, both my `onCreate()` and `onResume()` are pretty resource-intensive, they e.g. re-color bitmaps and dynamically set up the UI. This is unfortunately needed and can't be carried out asynchronously, as the user should see the final UI right from the beginning.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for trying it out on your end! I'll try to post some sample code. Could you add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in your `onCreate()` and `onResume()`? From my understanding of the order in which `onCreate()`, `onResume()` and `onAttachedToWindow()` are called, this shouldn't make any difference (it should just delay the Activity from popping up, rather than leading to the keyguard being shown for 2 seconds)

Comment: Hey Nick, per your request I added the `Thread.sleep(1000)` call to both `onCreate()` and `onResume()`. On my Rezound & Ally, I get a black screen as it sleeps on both create & resume before displaying. However, on my Xperia Active (running 4.0.4), I hit a loop before the device wakes up, and sometimes I do indeed get the keyguard prior to the view!


You're correct that `onAttachedToWindow()` fires in the lifecycle _after_ the `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, and `onResume()` callbacks fire.

Comment: Nick, out of curiosity, which activity has the `Window.addFlags()` call? Your launcher activity, or another? And are you calling `finish()` anywhere?

Comment: Well you have mentioned your problem right here `both my onCreate() and onResume() are pretty resource-intensive, they e.g. re-color bitmaps`. You will get even ANR if you will try to block UI for more that ~5 sec. Instead you must do heavy lifting of bitmaps in background thread. Or prepare your bitmaps in your service, save them to sdcard and in your `Activity` just read them from sd card (of course from background thread). Reading bitmap won't take long so hopefully user won't notice anything.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh, I should rephrase that, I'm applying a `ColorFilter` to an existing bitmap, so I'm not actually doing anything where loading the bitmap from storage would be quicker. When I launch the activity from a button (i.e. not from the background and without the keyguard showing), the UI-thread is blocked for maybe 1 second max.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for your tests! The activity that has the `Window.addFlags()` call is a "random" activity, i.e. not the launcher activity. I'm calling `finish()` after the user has "acknowledged" my activity, but not in any unusual places (like `onPause()`, for example). The activity awakes the screen at a number of points during the day, so my app's other activities are probably no longer in the activity stack in most instances.

Comment: I noticed that in my sample app, if I called `finish()` in the same activity that called `addFlags()`, the keyguard would not function properly. Moving the keyguard flag to another activity or removing the call to `finish()` fixed the issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried UI Thread. Try to look at this good tutorial http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/tag/ui-thread/. Hopre this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD permission to your manifest xml

source : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234156/how-to-disable-keyguard-and-display-an-activity-to-the-user-when-receiver-of-scr)

Comment: Hi AT_AB, thanks for your answer. The WindowManager flag `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` doesn't require this permission, as it only dismisses the "insecure" (swipe) keyguard. But the link you provided actually also mentions the problem I'm facing and it seems it doesn't happen when the "old" keyguard-methods are used.