# Robotium (Android) - View isn't visible by Robotium tests

Tags: android, textview, robotium, visible

I am having trouble when testing with Robotium for an exercise on a Coursera course... I'll try to explain the better way possible for you to understand.

I have an activity with a TextView created programmatically on the onCreate method, I'm sure the View is coded right and actually, when I run the Robotium tests with my own device, it passes all the tests IF the screen is on, but if I run the tests with my screen off/device locked Robotium fails in an assertTrue with the waitForView method.

The problem is that I can't be sure the screen that run the tests in the Coursera platform is on (and it doesn't 'cause it fails with the same error I have when I try to run the tests with the screen off).
I think it has something to do with Robotium... but I'm not sure what should I do to make my TextView visible in the sense Robotium can waitForView on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Robotium` is an instrumentation test framework, which is close to your app's UI, so it would click on button only if it sees it.

I don't know what Coursera course you're talking about, and why you're thinking that their tests are running on screen lock - which is certainly impossible, but I can swear that if you would use Espresso instead of Robotium it would also fail.

Find on your phone/emulator function `Stay awake`.

You may need first to unlock 'Developers Options' on your device. To do it choose `Settings` than  click on `About phone`, finally click several times on `Build version`.

According to [Unlocking the emulator or device for Android test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342221/unlocking-the-emulator-or-device-for-android-test)

> I've had the same problems with unreliable unlocking when running
>   Robotium tests. I did not find a solution to programmaticly unlock
>   devices that worked reliably, but there are two things that I did as a
>   work-around.
>
> - Just disable the lock screen (`Settings -> Security -> Screen lock -> None`). Not ideal but at the end of the day, reliable tests are the important thing.
> - Enable "Stay Awake" settings to keep the screen from turning off due to inactivity (`Settings -> Developer options -> Stay awake`). Some
>     OEM/phones either don't have that option or still turn off anyways, so
>     for those pesky devices I installed the [KeepScreenOn][1] app.
>
> **Warning: leaving the screen on, sitting on the home screen, for 24 hours a day may cause some screen burn-in/ghosting.** I'm not sure if
>   this is permanent, but be aware of this. In our case, we were using
>   dedicated test devices so it was not a big deal.
>
> Also note that since the phones will have their screen on at all
>   times, you may want to dim the brightness to use less battery power
>   (charging over USB can be slow sometimes).

I think you can also use `uiautomator` code in `setUp` method, which would check if screen is locked. If `true`, unlock the device screen.